# Split one record in to multiple record based on quantity in sql server in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

Here my table **Asset** having one record having quantity greater than 1
[image]

when i click on split button then i want to having each single entry i.e if quantity is 3 then i want to divide cost with 3 and add new two entry same table and update old entry , following image show excepted result

[image]

Comment: how to assign the new asset id ? just increment by 1 ?

Comment: yes its autoincremented

Comment: What if the Cost is 30000 and Quantity is 7 ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: 7 entries with Asset Id A1-A7, cost =4286 something for each entry and quantity is 1 for each

Comment: Here am write round value. 4285.714

Answer (score 1):

using a tally or number table. Here I am using recursive CTE to dynamically create one

```
; with number as
(
    select  n = 1
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    number
    where   n < 99
)
select  a.*,
        SplitCost = a.Cost / a.Quantity,
        SplitQty  = 1
from    @Asset a
        inner join number n on  n.n <= a.Quantity
```

Note : no matter what is your data type for your cost column, after you dividing it by quantity, if you add up all the individual cost after splitting, you might not get back your original value.

Comment: I would add a caution to this. This type of cte is known as a counting rcte which is very inefficient because it is really doing a loop behind the scenes. There are some better ways to generate a tally table on the fly. See this article for an in depth look at counting with recursive ctes. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
DECLARE @MyAsset TABLE 
  (
    [AssetId] INT,
    [AssetName] Varchar(20),
    [Qty] int
  )

INSERT @MyAsset
    VALUES (1,'Computer', 3),
           (2,'Printer', 2)


SELECT
    [AssetId]
    ,[AssetName]
    ,1 AS [Qty]
FROM @MyAsset t
INNER JOIN master..spt_values num
    ON num.type = 'p'
    AND num.number < t.Qty
```

**Result**

```
AssetId AssetName   Qty
------------------------
1       Computer    1
1       Computer    1
1       Computer    1
2       Printer     1
2       Printer     1
```